# Swipe animation on fragment

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments

Iv seen other post's that attempt to answer this but don't quite cover it. So hopefully somebody could clear this up.

I have an activity that displays a card, the idea is when you swipe right/left/up the card will move in that direction following the users finger movement the way ViewPager works for scrolling left right. What is the simplest way to implement this kind of animation ? Are there an Open Source libs that do this already ?

I currently have a slide_in/slide_out animation that is used in when calling replace in fragment manager but this applies the animation after the swipe action and not during

(EDIT) I could use a scroller and scroll the view but I wanted something a little "cooler" like swiping through a deck of cards one card at a time.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I already use GestureDetector to detect the swipe action and the direction, the piece im missing is how to animate the fragment to follow the users finger like they are dragging/scrolling

Comment: you can use View.offsetLeftAndRight / View.offsetTopAndBottom or use ViewDragHelper (no need for GestureDetector) see: https://gist.github.com/pskink/b747e89c1e1a1e314ca6

Comment: I think you should be looking for Carousel swipe

Comment: This is the most terrible part of the android SDK - you always reinwenting the wheel with horizontal scrolling components.

Comment: @helleye Carousel Swipe works for left/right scrolling only I want that animation but on a fragment level and also for up and down

Comment: Are you looking for something like this perhaps? It's using viewpagers and looks to be simple enough to change to accomodate your requirements: http://stevenkideckel.wordpress.com/2014/04/07/a-rotating-page-transformer/

Comment: Yes, that is more like what I was looking for. Thank You, however still doesn't quite solve how to animate the upwards swipe, Android makes this so difficult

Comment: @Chris I need the exact same thing without upward and downward swipe. Can you please post your answer with swipe right and left ?